# VMware P2V on HDD with 2 OS - "How hack" Windows 7 System Partition (100mb)

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware, windows-server-2003

Hi I have  HDD with bad sectors. I would like use p2v from VMware. On HDD is installed Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003.

HDD is divided into these partition:

- C - Windows Server 2003
- D - Windows 7 - on this partition I have bad sectors
- G - Data

I would like have virtual machine  only from Windows Server 2003(C:) and Data(D:)
If I select in p2v process  only C: and G: partition I can boot from this virtual HDD.

First I installed Windows Server 2003 and then Windows 7. During installation of Windows 7 is created some system boot partion. Size of this partition is about 100mb.

I think problem is that this is boot partition and I must includ this partition to virtual disk.

My question is how can solve it? Because I cant see this partition during p2v process in vmware.

I would like create clean virtual machine with Windows Server 2003 without bootloader at start. I want have only C and G partion on virtual machine.

Thank for advice.